# What's the best SEO practice when you do an AJAX driven website?

Tags: ajax, web-crawler

I encountered several websites running in Ajax and it seems like their SEO is pretty bad, does Google really crawl websites like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimization guides for different search engines tell that bots are unable to crawl such sites. I think, Google's bots might use Chrome's engine for some purposes (I remember, they made site screenshots one time), but nevertheless, it's the static HTML that's important. Therefore, the usual practice would be generating valid HTML on the server to provide functional site for user agents like, for example, Lynx, and then patching it with AJAX, history API and all other imaginable bells and whistles.